# Reference request for the philosophy of meditation

Tags: reference-request

I would like to read some texts on the philosophy of or the philosophy behind meditation. By meditation, I mean the contemplative practice in certain Eastern religions, where one pays close attention to the breath or some other sense object. Are there even texts on that subject?

Comment: Buddhist texts are good sources for the philosophy behind meditation. Also Yoga Sutras by Patanjali based on Shamkya metaphysics

Comment: There are many "philosophies" behind meditation, because there are many kinds of meditations which aim for different goals. These "philosophies" range from the relatively scientific to the dubious and esoteric. If you want to understand the philosophies behind meditation, you have an enormous, although likely rather interesting task ahead of you. Much of meditation does not so much have a philosophy behind it, as a belief system. Many cults adapt the idea of mediation to their needs, often as a key to enlightenment.